# Mass Transit stops consuming after exception occurs

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus. Everything seems to work fine, except when my consumer throws an exception.

When it occurs, the message is shown as a dead letter in my subscription overview through Azure portal and then, the consumer stops consuming new incoming messages.

My configuration looks like this:

```
_azureServiceBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(new HostSettings
    {
        ServiceUri = new Uri(pharmacyEndpointSettings.Endpoint.BdcpServiceBus),
        TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp,
        TokenCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            pharmacyEndpointSettings.Endpoint.BdcpServiceTenantId,
            pharmacyEndpointSettings.Endpoint.BdcpServiceClientId,
            pharmacyEndpointSettings.Endpoint.BdcpServiceClientSecret)
    });
    
    cfg.UseMessageRetry(c => c.Immediate(5));
    cfg.AutoDeleteOnIdle = TimeSpan.FromDays(AutoDeleteSubscriptionOnIdleInDays);
    cfg.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(MessageTimeToLiveInDays);
    cfg.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true;

    cfg.Message<MyMessage>(m => m.SetEntityName("MyTopicName"));
    cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<T>(_subscriptionName.Value, se =>
    {
        se.Rule = new CreateRuleOptions("Receiver", new SqlRuleFilter("receiver='all' OR receiver='MySpecificReceiver'"));
        
        se.Consumer<MyMessage>();
        se.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport();
        se.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport();
    });
}

_azureServiceBus.Start();
```

My consumers look like this

```
public class MyMessageConsumer : IConsumer<T>
{
   public override Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)
   {

        if (context.Message.Id == "INVALID")
        {
            return Task.FromException(new Exception("invalid id"));
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

In the deadletter properties I find an OperationCancelledException

> à
> GreenPipes.Internals.Extensions.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<OrCanceled>g__WaitAsync|0>d.MoveNext() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à
> MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.SendEndpointContextFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() à GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() à
> GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() à GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à
> MassTransit.Transports.HostConfigurationRetryExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à
> MassTransit.Context.BaseConsumeContext.d__61`1.MoveNext() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() à MassTransit.Context.BaseConsumeContext.<NotifyFaulted>d__56`1.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à
> MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext<TMessage>>-Send>d__4.MoveNext() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() à GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.<SendToOutput>d__9.MoveNext() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() à GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.d__9.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.d__4.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à
> GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter<TContext>-Send>d__5.MoveNext() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() à GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter-Send>d__5.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à
> MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeadLetterFilter.<GreenPipes-IFilter-Send>d__3.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> à
> MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.d__17.MoveNext()

Edit:

Also I realized that the retry count is being increased without any hit inside the Consume method of the consumer.

It also appears that there are Azure.RequestFailedException, but I can't say when it happens since the consuming seem stopped.

> Service request failed. Status: 401 (Unauthorized) Content:
> `401`Authorization failed for specified
> action: Manage,EntityWrite.
> TrackingId:1d71f7fe-1627-4fe4-86fb-67446207d0a2_G11,
> SystemTracker:sb-staging-spoke.servicebus.windows.net:MassTransit_ReceiveFault,
> Timestamp:2022-12-09T19:38:52 Headers:
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
> Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8 Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2022
> 19:38:52 GMT Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Comment: MassTransit version?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson v7.3.1 and I can unfortunately not upgrade higher

Comment: I realized that I also sometimes get an UnauthorizedException... it does not seem consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to publish a `ReceiveFault`, and failing because it can't create the `ReceiveFault` topic. If you were to look in the logs, you might see why it can't deserialize the message. Ensuring the topic exists would help avoid the fault publish error, which might avoid whatever causes the issue.

However, version 7.3.1 is no longer supported. So I'd suggest trying to resolve whatever causes the issue. Making sure you have good logging enabled should help identify any other related issues.

### Update

You can disable fault publishing by setting `PublishFaults = false`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to not publish the fault? I tried to replace  se.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport(); and         se.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport(); by  se.DiscardSkippedMessages();  and
                se.DiscardFaultedMessages(); by it's not working